# Execute script within new tab created with chrome.tabs.create()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

How do I execute a script using chrome.tabs.executeScript() in the tab I've created using chrome.tabs.create(). I've searched around and none of the solutions seem to work.

This is my code currently.

```
    runContentScript(){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://google.com/", active: true});

        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id!, {file: "tracking.js"});
        });
    }
```

My manifest is correctly setup as well.

**EDIT:** Added full code as I'm not sure if wether something is interfering with the runContentScript function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Cart.css';
import logo from './greenlake_logo.png';
import { url } from 'inspector';

class ProductList extends Component<{}, {products: any[][]}> {
    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
        this.addProduct.bind(this);
        this.runContentScript.bind(this);
        this.checkIfPathsExists.bind(this)
        this.loadProductPage.bind(this);
        this.removeLocalStorage.bind(this);
        this.state = {products: []};
    }

    setLocalStorage(values: any[]){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'productList': values});
    }

    async appendLocalStorage(product: any[]){
        var promisedStorageValues = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            chrome.storage.sync.get('productList', function(result){
                resolve(result.productList);
            })
        });

        const values: any = await promisedStorageValues;
        const newValues: any[] = [];
        for(let i=0; i < values.length; i++){
            newValues.push(values[i]);
        }
        newValues.push(product);
        this.setLocalStorage(newValues);
        this.readLocalStorage();
    }

    async removeLocalStorage(product: any[]){
        var promisedStorageValues = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            chrome.storage.sync.get('productList', function(result){
                resolve(result.productList);
            })
        });

        const values: any = await promisedStorageValues;
        values.splice(values.indexOf(product, 0), 1);
        this.setLocalStorage(values);
        this.readLocalStorage();
    }

    async readLocalStorage(){
        var promisedStorageValues = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            chrome.storage.sync.get('productList', function(result){
                resolve(result.productList);
            })
        });

        const values: any = await promisedStorageValues;
        this.setState({products: values});
    }

    async addProduct(){
        var promisedURL = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                resolve([tabs[0].url, tabs[0].favIconUrl, tabs[0].title]);
            })
        });
        const urlInformation: any = await promisedURL;
        const urlFavicon: any = urlInformation[1];
        const urlProduct: any = urlInformation[0]
        var workaroundHost: any = new URL(urlInformation[0]);
        const urlHost: any = workaroundHost.host;
        const urlTitle: any = urlInformation[2];
        const urlPrice: any = 'placeholder';

        this.appendLocalStorage([urlProduct, urlFavicon, urlTitle, urlPrice, urlHost]);
    }

    loadProductPage(url: string){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: url, active: true});
    }

    runContentScript(urlProduct: string){
        chrome.tabs.create({url: urlProduct}, createdTab => {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function _(tabId, info, tab) {
              if (tabId === createdTab.id && info.url) {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(_);
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'tracking.js'});
              }
            });
        });
    }

    loadPath(url: string){
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/getpath/" + url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log('loadPath: ' + response)
        })
    }

    checkIfPathsExists(){
        for(let i=0; i < this.state.products.length; i++){
            const urlHost: string = this.state.products[i][4];
            let formattedHost = urlHost.split('.')[1];
            const status = fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/checkpath/" + formattedHost)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {if(response == true){this.loadPath(formattedHost)}else{this.runContentScript(this.state.products[i][0])}});
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.readLocalStorage();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="logoDiv">
                    <img src={logo} width="128" height="64" />
                </div>
                <div className="centeredDiv">
                    {this.state.products.map(product => {return (
                        <div>
                            <ListGroup horizontal id="Test">
                                <ListGroup.Item className="ProductListLogo" onClick={() => this.loadProductPage(product[0])}><img src={product[1]} width="32" height="32"></img></ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item className="ProductListProduct">{product[2]}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item className="ProductListPrice">{product[3]}</ListGroup.Item>
                                <ListGroup.Item className="ProductListAction" onClick={() => this.removeLocalStorage(product)}>X</ListGroup.Item>
                            </ListGroup>
                            <div className="spacerLine"/>
                        </div>
                    )})}
                </div>
                <div className="actionDiv">
                        <ListGroup horizontal>
                            <ListGroup.Item className="ActionButtons" onClick={() => this.addProduct()}>Add To Cart</ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item className="ActionButtons" onClick={() => this.checkIfPathsExists()}>Checkout</ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Cart extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="containerDiv">
                <div>
                    <ProductList />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Cart;
```

**SOLUTION**
You need to add "active: false" as if you create a tab it automatically focuses on it and closes extension if not specified. The callback function therefore never gets called.

```
        chrome.tabs.create({url: urlProduct, active: false}, createdTab => {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function _(tabId, info, tab) {
              if (tabId === createdTab.id && info.url) {
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(_);
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'tracking.js'});
              }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming manifest.json's `permissions` includes `"https://google.com/"` (or a broader pattern), there are three problems here.

#### 1. Workaround for Chrome bug on redirect

[crbug.com/820080](https://crbug.com/820080): chrome.tabs.executeScript may fail if the passed tab is **undergoing a main frame navigation.** You're specifying `https://google.com/` but there's no site there, it redirects to `https://www.google.com/` which you don't see in the new Chrome as it hides `www`. Either [enable showing full URLs](https://superuser.com/a/1498561) or use `location.href` in devtools console to view the real URL.

Verdict: since any site can decide to perform a redirect for whatever reason so the reliable solution is to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated but do it correctly, see below.

#### 2. Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated correctly

- Use the created tab id in the callback to limit onUpdated to just that tab
- Unregister the listener to prevent accumulation of listeners which would cause bugs

#### 3. Prevent popup from auto-closing

Opening an active/focused tab closes the currently shown extension popup, it completely terminates, so the callback for create() won't run as it's invoked asynchronously.

- **Workaround.**

  A simple workaround is to open the tab as inactive then focus it:

  ```js
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://google.com/', active: false}, createdTab => {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function _(tabId, info, tab) {
      if (tabId === createdTab.id && info.url) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(_);
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'tracking.js'}, () => {
          chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {active: true});
          // the above will close the popup if it doesn't have its own devtools open
        });
      }
    });
  });
  ```
- **Solution.**

  A reliable solution is to do it in the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) because the above workaround may fail if another extension is modifying the default behavior of new tabs and forcefully focuses your tab, which auto-closes the popup and breaks the workaround.

  popup.js:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    cmd: 'openTab',
    url: 'https://google.com/',
    script: 'tracking.js',
  });
  ```

  background.js:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (msg.cmd === 'openTab') {
      chrome.tabs.create({url: msg.url}, createdTab => {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function _(tabId, info, tab) {
          if (tabId === createdTab.id && info.url) {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(_);
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: msg.script});
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: I copied your code and it still won't work. I've tried troubleshooting more and can't figure out what's wrong. It seems as it doesn't even run the create callback function but I'm not sure. I added an alert('working') before initializing the onUpdated and that doesn't run.

Comment: I added the cart components code to the post if you have time to debug. I really appreciate it. Excuse the messy code, I'm just trying to get it working.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for your help! I used your solution and found that the reason for it not working was that as I opened a new tab with chrome.tabs.create() it focused that tab and closed the extension and therefore not executing the callback function.

Comment: Your explanation completely resolved my doubts about why this isn't working, understanding the reason allows me to figure it out even myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) callback function.

```
runContentScript(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://google.com/', active: true}, tab => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'tracking.js'}); 
    });

}
```

Comment: That's the first thing I did and it doesn't work :/ I've tried adding listeners and waiting for rendering until executing script and that doesnt work either. I've also tried the argument in executeScript, "runAt" and doesn't make a difference